# Arrayformula not filling column when using query and multiple importranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hey all I have the following formula but it isn't filling the rest of the column.  It isn't even giving me an error when there is something else in a cell below it.

```
=arrayformula(IFERROR(QUERY(
{IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 1","Original!A:G");
IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 2","Original!A:G");
IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 3","Original!A:G");
IMPORTRANGE("SHeet 4","Original!A:G")}
,"Select Col7 where Col3='"&E4:E&"'",0), " "))
```

Does anyone have any idea why? If I don't use arrayformula and put the equation into each cell individually, it takes forever to load.

Comment: Could you provide a sample sheet or screenshot of your data?

Comment: The reason why you're not getting any errors returned is because you're using IFERROR to return an empty string "". Also as stated by Nikko above, please share a dummy spreadsheet we can work on so we can get an idea what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: I assume "Sheet 1", etc., is an actual sheet ID. That said, QUERY doesn't work on arrays like "where Col3 = [some array]." This should be setup as a VLOOKUP of ranges C:G only instead of any kind of QUERY. But since we don't have access to your spreadsheet, data or layout, that's as much as I can tell you.

Comment: Arrayformula does not work with Query. You can't go through E4:E this way

Comment: @ErikTyler I wish I could mark yours as the answer as that did it.

Comment: Tarik, I didn't post it as an actual solution, because it doesn't have enough form to it as stated. But I'm glad that steered you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Change your SELECT-clause to

```
"Select Col7 where Col3 matches'"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, E4:E)&"'"
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: Hey that stared to fill the rows but it was returning wrong values :/